# Does IEC-61131 Structured Text allow comparison of boolean operands?

Tags: plc, relational, st

I'm building a parser and type checker for Structured Text.  ST is a derivative of Pascal.

It is clear that ST allows equality comparison of two declared real variables X and Y as

```
 X = Y
```

It is also clear you can write

```
 X <> Y
```

and

```
 X > Y
```

If I have two declared boolean variables A and B, is

```
 A = B
```

legal?  Pascal would certainly say so.   The reference documents I have for ST (including an Australian version of the 2004 standard, and several vendors implementations) are unclear.

Can I write:

```
 A > B
```

and what does it mean?

[In the abstract, I'm interested in the same questions for comparing strings.  Brownie  points for addressing that issue too].

[No, I can't just try it on a real controller; I don't actually have one and the nearest one is effectively two days away from me.]

What's the answer, and what's the reference document you consulted that shows the answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to this question really depends on IDE. Although there is a standard for ST, every vendor implement it little bit differently.

In general this is valid statement.

```
VAR
    a, b: BOOL;
END_VAR

IF a = b THEN
   // Do something
END_IF
```

Here is what is in IEC 61131-3 draft. Unfortunately it is not open document and costs money that is why I cannot post it here or provide a link.

https://webstore.iec.ch/publication/4552

1. `GT` `>` Decreasing sequence: `OUT := (IN1>IN2) & (IN2>IN3) & ... & (INn-1 > INn)`
2. `GE` `>=` Monotonic sequence: `OUT := (IN1>=IN2)&(IN2>=IN3)& ... & (INn-1 >= INn)`
3. `EQ` `=` Equality: `OUT := (IN1=IN2) & (IN2=IN3) & ... & (INn-1 = INn)`
4. `LE` `<`= Monotonic sequence: `OUT := (IN1<=IN2)&(IN2<=IN3)& ... & (INn-1 <= INn)`
5. `LT` `<` Increasing sequence: `OUT := (IN1<IN2) & (IN2<IN3) & ... & (INn-1 < INn)`
6. `NE` `<>` Inequality (non-extensible) `OUT := (IN1 <> IN2)`

This also means that in some IDEs you can use

```
IF EQ(a, b) THEN
   // Do something
END_IF
```

And this should be valid as well.

> Can I write:
>       A > B
>   and what does it mean?

If `A` greater than `B` this expression will return `TRUE` otherwise `FALSE`.

Comment: Great, chapter and verse quote.  Just what I needed.  Thanks!